# How to print Text 'Continued..." in all pages except last page in XML Publisher Report? This is not the common requirement in the reports

Tags: xml, xml-publisher

How to print Text 'Continued..." in all pages except last page in XML Publisher Report? I wanted to share the solution with screen shots so that in future this can be referred directly and can be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

We had a requirement in one of the report to print text "Continued..." in all pages except last page in XML Publisher Report. After inputs from technical folks I was able to achieve that by following:

1. In Form field "init pt" we need to add below text:

   < ?init-page-total:pt?>
2. In Form field "close_pt" we need to add below text:

   < ?end-page-total:pt?>
3. In Form field "Carried Forward" we need to add below text:

< xdofo:inline-total display-condition="exceptlast" name="pt">Continued...< /xdofo:inline-total>

4. In the Footer section we will call template as below:

< ?call-template:CarryFwd?>

This will print text "Continued..." in all pages except last page.

[image: Form Field placement]

[image: Footer section]